# What is the developer experience like building on Solana versus other popular Blockchain platforms

Tags: web3.js, rust

As a relatively new blockchain developer it would be great to gain some perspective from more experienced Solana developers on their opinion of building on Solana.

More specifically,

1. What are the largest pros & cons in your experience of building on Solana?
2. If you've built on other blockchain ecosystems(Cosmos, Ethereum/EVM chains, Aptos/Sui) how
   would you compare the developer tooling & general experience to Solana?

Outside of these two questions, anything else you'd like to share that you think may be helpful would be greatly appreciated.